# Laravel 10 unwanted Printing of File Content in Console\Commands

Tags: php, laravel, console

I load a text file with

```
file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/Modell.php');
```

the first line in this file is `startphp` instead of `<?php`. It will be replaced later.
I want this file in a variable to change and add some stuff and then write it to a new file.
My Problem is that the file gets displayed in the Console every time I execute the command. Is there a way to tell Console\Commands to not echo anything until the "success" Message?
Or at least don't echo the file.

The Script works so far but it's just annoying.
Thank you for your help. Even a few words what to google would help. I didn't find anything or searched the wrong terms.

I didn't find anything or searched the wrong terms.
To reproduce the error do this in Terminal:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel error 4.2 --prefer-dist
cd error
php artisan make:command Test
mkdir app/Console/Commands/templates/
echo "startphp\n echo 'Hallo';"> app/Console/Commands/templates/temp.php
php artisan serve
php artisan app:test
```

and add

```
file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/temp.php');
```

into the handle() function.

Given that the file exists and has a .php ending it will print the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution. The code was printed because the templates I user were .php endings. Changed it to .txt and nothing unwanted was printed. Thx for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--quiet` option.

For example, if command is `example:command`, you can run it like below:

```
php artisan example:command --quiet
```

This will preventing any unwanted printing of file content.